# Print each field of CSV on newline without knowing number of fields

Tags: bash, text-processing, csv-simple

I was playing with IFS today and created a quick text file with a list of numbers separated by commas on 1 line.

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

I then tried to write a script to print each number on a newline. I was able to make it work, but I had to know how many fields there were. I'm trying to figure out how to do this on a list that's much longer where I wouldn't want to specify every field.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=,
while read num1 num2 num3 num4 num5
do
printf $num1"\n"
printf $num2"\n"
printf $num3"\n"
printf $num4"\n"
printf $num5"\n"
printf "\n"
done < "$1"
```

This gives me the output:

```
keismbp13b:tmp$ ./ifs.sh list
1
2
3
4
5
keismbp13b:tmp$
```

I'm thinking I may have to use awk or something similar to separate the list onto newlines but I am curious if there is another way.

Thanks!

I also realized just after posting that I could do this

```
tr , "\n" < list
```

Is there anyway to do this without separating the list first?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you pointed in your question it's can be done with `tr` command as follows:

```
tr ',' '\n' < infile
```

and here are other options to do that.

```
sed -e $'s/,/\\\n/g' infile
```

Or:

```
sed 's/,/\
/g' infile.txt
```

Or in some `sed` implementations, use:

```
sed 's/,/\n/g' infile
```

Or via `awk` (if you don't mind last empty line):

```
awk -v RS=',' '1' infile
```

Or in `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line; do 
    echo "${line//,/$'\n'}";
done < infile
```

Or reading to an array and then `printf`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read -a fields; do
    printf "%s\n" "${fields[@]}";
done < infile
```

- considering each field separated with comma as like `..., 2 4, ...` at above, else, you can add it to `IFS` from `IFS=','` to `IFS=', '` to print in separate.