# How to reformat text in a file to another direction?

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I have table in the current format:

```
Lead:Arrow1:Arrow2:Arrow3
Follow:Arrow4:Arrow5:Arrow6:Arrow7:Arrow8:Arrow9
```

I want to turn this to the

```
Lead
Arrow1
Arrow2
Arrow3
Follow
Arrow4
Arrow5
Arrow6
Arrow7
Arrow8
Arrow9
```

I tried `awk`:

```
$(awk -F":" '/Lead/ {print NF-1}' $f)
$(awk -F":" '/Follow/ {print NF-1}' $f)
```

but it didn't work. How can I do it in `awk` or any other method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print each field of CSV on newline without knowing number of fields](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386840/print-each-field-of-csv-on-newline-without-knowing-number-of-fields)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `tr` as follows:

```
<file tr ":" "\n"

Lead
Arrow1
Arrow2
Arrow3
Follow
Arrow4
Arrow5
Arrow6
Arrow7
Arrow8
Arrow9
```

or `awk` as follows:

```
<file awk '{gsub(/:/,"\n")}1'
Lead
Arrow1
Arrow2
Arrow3
Follow
Arrow4
Arrow5
Arrow6
Arrow7
Arrow8
Arrow9
```

Comment: Nice, with GNU awk you could also write `awk -v RS='[:\n]' 1`

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` as you suggested:

```
$ awk '{ gsub(":", "\n", $0); print }' <file
Lead
Arrow1
Arrow2
Arrow3
Follow
Arrow4
Arrow5
Arrow6
Arrow7
Arrow8
Arrow9
```

This simply replaces each `:` in the input data with a newline.

---

Another `awk` solution which uses the `OFS` (Output Field Separator) variable:

```
awk -v OFS='\n' -F ':' '{ $1=$1; print }' <file
```

The assignment `$1=$1` looks bogus but it forces `awk` to reformat the current input record according to `OFS` (and `ORS`, but we don't change that from the default, which is a newline), which in this case means inserting newlines between all `:`-delimited fields.

---

With `awk`, we could also just iterate over the `:`-delimited fields and print them individually:

```
awk -F ':' '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) print $i }' <file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another super-simple solution would be to convert the `:`s to spaces with sed, and then print the words with `echo` in a `for` loop:

```
for i in $(sed 's/:/ /g')
do
  echo $i
done
```

This script works from stdin to stdout.